# display a specific branch and hide the others (jstree)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jstree

First of all, thank you for your contribution.
I use JStree with PHP and Mysql, and I want to display a specific branch (I explain, I want to use it as a menu and each user has its own list)
I am a beginner in Jquery and I do not know how to use or modify it.
thank you again
[image]

I use the code of vakarta avec class.tree.php et class.db.php

```
$('#tree')
            .jstree({
                'core' : {
                    'data' : {
                        'url' : '../php/TreeEvent.php?operation=get_node',
                        'data' : function (node) {
                            return { 'id' : node.id };
                        }
                    },
                    'check_callback' : true,
                    'themes' : {
                        'responsive' : false,
                        "rtl": true,
                        "theme" : "default-rtl",
                        "icons" : true
                    }
                },

                'force_text' : true,
                'plugins' : ['state','dnd','contextmenu','changed']
            })
```

le code PHP

```
if(isset($_GET['operation'])) {
$fs = new tree(db::get('mysqli://root:mdp@127.0.0.1/db_test'), array('structure_table' => 'tree_struct', 'data_table' => 'tree_data', 'data' => array('nm')));
    try {
    $rslt = null;
    switch($_GET['operation']) {
        case 'analyze':
            var_dump($fs->analyze(true));
            die();
            break;
        case 'get_node':
            $node = isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] !== '#' ? (int)$_GET['id'] : 0;
            $temp = $fs->get_children($node);
            $rslt = array();
            foreach($temp as $v) {
                $rslt[] = array('id' => $v['id'], 'text' => $v['nm'], 'children' => ($v['rgt'] - $v['lft'] > 1));
            }
            break;
        case "get_content":
            $node = isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] !== '#' ? $_GET['id'] : 0;
            $node = explode(':', $node);
            if(count($node) > 1) {
                $rslt = array('content' => 'Multiple selected');
            }
            else {
                $temp = $fs->get_node((int)$node[0], array('with_path' => true));
                $rslt = array('content' => '->' . implode('/',array_map(function ($v) { return $v['nm']; }, $temp['path'])). '/'.$temp['nm']);
            }
            break;
```

Comment: Can you please show the code you have now?

Comment: Without seeing current context including relevant parts of your code and sample data, it's really impossible to give you anything but vague suggestions.

Comment: I add a commentaires

Comment: I have posted a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62632209/yii2-show-hide-kartik-treeview-nodes) can you please see it ?